# What is Hilbert Space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

What is [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space)? Please explain in it in very easy English. I've seen so many answers here that are so easy to understand but the language itself makes it hard to understand. That is why I have asked the question again. Please use easy terms and explain them too a little. Answer as you would explain it to a fourteen-year-old. And are all of these spaces related to dimensions?

Edit
In respond to chair i have come to know that hilbert space can be of any dimension but i think every space with a dimension is a vector space.

Comment: So that those that may wish to write an answer may know where to start, would you please edit your question to list some of what you *do* know with regards to Hilbert space?  For example, are you familiar with none, some, or all of the following:  (1) vector space, (2) inner product, (3) completeness?

Comment: It is an infinite dimensional space where nevertheless Pythagorean theorem is valid.

Comment: @ValterMoretti A Hilbert space needn't be infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Not actually, it requires completeness, but this fact in the finite dimensional case is trivial. There is no difference in the finite dim case between a Hilbert space and a (complex) vector space equipped with a (Hermitian) scalar product. Completeness is the crucial property.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5778). Can you edit your question to mention some things you're already familiar with or things you've found while reading about this topic?

Comment: OP wrote: _I think every space with a dimension is a vector space._ The 2-sphere is 2-dimensional. How is it a vector space?

Comment: Qmechanic Mike says that vectors are similar to matrices but matrices represent a point on the graph ( the xy matrice does) but vectors are kinda arrows pointing out to different directions so what is its relationship with a matrix

Comment: Sorry that was a stupid comment on my behalf, i realised that starting from (0,0) to any point on the graph is a vector

Answer (score 2):

At the level of this question, there are just two simple things to know about Hilbert spaces:

1. They are [vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space).
2. There is an "inner product" that takes a pair of vectors and returns a scalar.

The first point is really easy, but may be just a little more abstract than you're used to.  Remember that vectors aren't just the usual three-dimensional things you use in elementary physics (though that is one example) — they're any collection of objects that you can add together to get another similar object, and can multiply by a scalar.  One familiar example would be matrices of a given shape: you can add a pair of them to get another matrix of that same shape, and you can multiply a matrix by a scalar to get another matrix of the same shape.  So you can say that matrices *are* vectors.  Of course, the most important example of a Hilbert space for quantum mechanics is the space of functions — and specifically complex-valued functions of location and time.  You can add two *functions* together to get a function that just returns the same of the values of those first two, and you can multiply a function by a scalar to get another function that just returns the value of the original function multiplied by that scalar.  So again, functions form a vector space.

The second point is also pretty easy, and again just a little more abstract than you're used to.  You're probably familiar with the most obvious type of inner product, which is just the usual dot product of three-dimensional vectors — it takes two vectors and gives you a scalar.  For matrices, you just take the product of one with the other's transpose, and then take the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) — again, you take two matrices (the "vectors" in this case), and you get a single scalar out.  Finally, you get back to the important example of complex-valued functions.  Now you might wonder how to take two functions and wind up with just one single scalar.  The obvious answer is integration: you multiply the two functions together (usually taking the complex conjugate of the second), and then integrate.

Now, that's really the basic idea, and it should seem quite simple.  Of course, this is all just at the introductory level.  As you get into more advanced quantum mechanics, you start to meet more complicated Hilbert spaces, and need more detailed and nuanced understanding of the features of Hilbert spaces.  And it is useful to think about these things more abstractly at some point.  But for now, you can get familiar with the concept just through these basic and concrete examples.

Answer (score 1):

What is Hilbert space? It is a mathematical abstraction, that can be thought of as a space where vectors can point in various directions, and be added to one another and multiplied by scalars. To be precise and thorough you would need various definitions, as alluded to by other answers here, but the essential point is that in a given Hilbert space all the vectors have the same number of components (equal to the dimension of the space) and these components can be complex numbers. In order to make sure standard methods of manipulation work in a neat and useful way with such vectors, the complex conjugate has to be introduced at the right moment in the calculation when a scalar product is formed (see textbooks for details).